# window.scrollBy fires before hash/anchor scroll in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a frustrating problem. I use the following in script inside of a jQuery load block:

```
window.scrollBy(0,-100);
```

I do it because I set a div to be fixed at the top of the page through scrolling, and this line will compensate so that the anchor you've clicked to (http://page.html#foo) is seen where it should be.

It works great in Firefox. In Chrome and Safari, it doesn't, because the load event appears to happen before the browser scrolls to the anchor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Include code + a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) (to simulate AJAX - see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Other than $(function () {});, you're pretty much already looking at the code. It will scroll the page up in Firefox, not in Chrome/Safari, when the URL includes a hash to scroll to an anchor.

Comment: Look here:
http://coasterbuzz.com/
Then the commented out stuff here:
http://coasterbuzz.com/Scripts/CB.js
Imagine then a link like this:
http://coasterbuzz.com/Forums/Topic/cedar-point-announces-fast-lane-on-facebook#860269

The code to adjust the scroll fires *before* the browser has scrolled to the anchor.

Comment: No, I can't. I told you the one line of code involved. The rest is irrelevant. If you're not interested in helping, then don't.

Answer (score 1):

I came across into the same problem, and this is my work out. (A hack actually)

```
// Clicking on the navigation bar
$('.navbar-nav a').click(function(e) {
    // Blocking default clicking event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Scroll to the anchored element with a delay
    setTimeout(function() {$('#talks')[0].scrollIntoView();}, 5);
    // Compensate the scrolling with another delay
    setTimeout(function() {scrollBy(0, -$('#info').height())}, 10);
}
```

It seems like it's a Safari bug.

Comment: Webkit* bug - still the case in 2016

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this problem. Using a timeout, even 0 ms, seems to work without visible jumping. Try this:

```
window.setTimeout()
{
    window.scrollBy(0, -100);
}, 0);
```